# ParamConverterProvider not working on Wildfly > 10.1.0 Final

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I was using `ParamConverterProvider` to automatically convert byte array to base64 and the other way around when using Jax-RS to create REST web service.

I have an endpoint that looks like this:

```
@POST
    public SignResponse Sign(SigRequest sigRequest) {
        SignResponse response = new SignResponse();
        try {
            response.setSignedHash(createDetachedSig(sigRequest.getHash()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Where my `SigRequest` looks like this:

```
public class SigRequest {

    private byte[] hash;

    public byte[] getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(byte[] hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }



}
```

And my `SigResponse` looks like this:

```
public class SignResponse {

        private byte[] signedHash;

        public byte[] getSignedHash() {
            return signedHash;
        }
        public void setSignedHash(byte[] signedHash) {
            this.signedHash = signedHash;
        }

    }
```

I implemented `ParamConverterProvider` interface like this:

```
@Provider
public class MyParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        System.out.println(rawType + " " + genericType + " " + annotations);
        if (rawType.equals(byte[].class)) {
            return (ParamConverter<T>) new Base64ParamConverter();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I also implemented *ParamConverter* for *byte[]* like this:

```
public class Base64ParamConverter implements ParamConverter<byte[]>{

      public byte[] fromString(String s){
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
      }

      public String toString(byte[] bytes){ 
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
      }

    }
```

This code worked fine on Wildfly 10.1.0 Final. However, when I try it on any version greater then 10.1.0 Final, including 11.0.0 and the latest (17.0.1 Final) it just doesn't work. I get 400 - Bad Request and the code never reaches `MyParamConverterProvider`'s `getConverter()` method.

Comment: `ParamConverterProvider` is meant to be used for `@XxxParam` parameters. Your example shows an entity body parameter (no annotation).

Comment: I guessed that was the case. But, it worked on Wiildfly 10 and I don't see the reason why it shouldn't be used for body params as well

Comment: It's not specified to. That's not what it was made for.